# Docker build failing on private hosted agent (Azure DevOps)

Tags: docker, azure-devops, debian-buster

I am trying to build a dockerfile on a private-hosted Azure DevOps agent, which is behind a corporate proxy. The base image is python/3.8.3-slim-buster. When I run apt-get update I get the following errors:

```
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  470  status code 470 [IP: 151.101.36.204 80]
Err:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  470  status code 470 [IP: 151.101.36.204 80]
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  470  status code 470 [IP: 151.101.36.204 80]
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  470  status code 470 [IP: 151.101.36.204 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  470  status code 470 [IP: 151.101.36.204 80]
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  470  status code 470 [IP: 151.101.36.204 80]
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease' is not signed.
```

Now the tricky part is that if I log in to this agent manually, and give the docker build command there it works fine. Also building on a Microsoft hosted agent works fine.

I pass the proxy configuration with --build-arg flags to the Dockerfile.

Anyone any idea where the error could be?

Edit: 
I tried adding the "--allow-releaseinfo-change" flag, still the same error. I have the feeling it somehow proxy related but can't figure out where to start looking.

Comment: Can you check if this will help you https://superuser.com/questions/1456989/how-to-configure-apt-in-debian-buster-after-release ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @KrzysztofMadej I did try adding the '--allow-releaseinfo-change' flag, still same error.

Comment: Ok, so you tried `apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change` and it doesn't work. But did you try `apt update --allow-releaseinfo-change`?

Comment: Just tried apt update as wel, same error. Plus added complication that Hadolint does not like 'apt' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I learned apt-get keeps the proxy-configuration somewhere else, as in my environment variables HTTP_PROXY & HTTPS_PROXY were not picked up.

Creating a proxy.conf and copying that to the container solved my problem as mentioned here:
https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-apt-for-ubuntu-18-04/